# Rest web service calling- XML POST request - iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, rest, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a problem regarding xml calling to REST web service, I have to pass following parameters to my web services in following format;

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/gayanAPI/GayanRESTService.svc/login

[image]

So I write a code for this.But its make Some error. (**Response Code: 400**) My sample code is below;

```
  //prepare request
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/gayanAPI/GayanRESTService.svc/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//set headers
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Login xmlns="">"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<UserId>%@</UserId>",@"200"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<PassWord>%@</PassWord>",@"123"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<ResId>%@</ResId>",@"1000"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<DeviceId>%@</DeviceId>",@"1234"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</Login>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//post
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result); 
    //here you get the response 
}
```

What is the reason for it. I this I made a mistake when Im creating XML request. Please help me to solve this? can you give me a code for this? I was fed up with this.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line,

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Login xmlns="">"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You need to quote double quotes (") with backslash (\) as follows:

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Login xmlns=\"\">"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I'm not sure if it causes the error, though.